# undefined reference when compiling code with cfitsio library

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, libraries, undefined-reference

I am receiving an **undefined reference** error for every function used from the **cfitsio** library when compiling my code. Below is the relevant chunk of the **make null** command's output (Note that **-L/usr/lib/ -lcfitsio** is in the first line):

```
gcc -g -I../mdl/null   -DCHABRIER -DCHANGESOFT -DDENSITYU -DDENSITYUNOTP -DDIFFUSION -DDODVDS -DDTADJUST -DEPSACCH -DPARTICLESPLIT -DPROMOTE -DGASOLINE -DJEANSSOFT -DNSMOOTHINNER -DRTFORCE -DSETTRAPFPE -DSTARFORM -DTHERMALCOND -DTOPHATFEEDBACK -DTWOPHASE -DVSIGVISC -DWENDLAND -DRADIATION -DRADIATIONLUM -DDDSIMPLE -DR2PPBMAX -DCOOLING_METAL  -L/usr/lib/ -lcfitsio  -I/usr/include/fitsio.h -o gasoline.dfTest main.o master.o param.o outtype.o pkd.o pst.o grav.o ewald.o walk.o eccanom.o hypanom.o fdl.o htable.o smooth.o smoothfcn.o collision.o qqsmooth.o cooling_metal.o cosmo.o romberg.o starform.o feedback.o millerscalo.o supernova.o supernovaia.o startime.o stiff.o runge.o dumpframe.o dffuncs.o dumpvoxel.o rotbar.o special.o ssio.o   treezip.o log.o radiation.o erf.o v_sqrt1.o ../mdl/null/mdl.o -lm
dumpframe.o: In function `fitsError':
/.../dumpframe.c:2156: undefined reference to `ffrprt'
dumpframe.o: In function `dfFinishFrame':
/.../dumpframe.c:2175: undefined reference to `ffinit'
/.../dumpframe.c:2176: undefined reference to `ffcrim'
/.../dumpframe.c:2197: undefined reference to `ffppr'
/.../dumpframe.c:2198: undefined reference to `ffclos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'gasoline.dfTest' failed
make[1]: *** [gasoline.dfTest] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/grondjj/Code/gasoline'
Makefile:457: recipe for target 'null' failed
make: *** [null] Error 2gcc -g -I../mdl/null   -DCHABRIER -DCHANGESOFT -DDENSITYU -DDENSITYUNOTP -DDIFFUSION -DDODVDS -DDTADJUST -DEPSACCH -DPARTICLESPLIT -DPROMOTE -DGASOLINE -DJEANSSOFT -DNSMOOTHINNER -DRTFORCE -DSETTRAPFPE -DSTARFORM -DTHERMALCOND -DTOPHATFEEDBACK -DTWOPHASE -DVSIGVISC -DWENDLAND -DRADIATION -DRADIATIONLUM -DDDSIMPLE -DR2PPBMAX -DCOOLING_METAL  -L/usr/lib/ -lcfitsio  -I/usr/include/fitsio.h -o gasoline.dfTest main.o master.o param.o outtype.o pkd.o pst.o grav.o ewald.o walk.o eccanom.o hypanom.o fdl.o htable.o smooth.o smoothfcn.o collision.o qqsmooth.o cooling_metal.o cosmo.o romberg.o starform.o feedback.o millerscalo.o supernova.o supernovaia.o startime.o stiff.o runge.o dumpframe.o dffuncs.o dumpvoxel.o rotbar.o special.o ssio.o   treezip.o log.o radiation.o erf.o v_sqrt1.o ../mdl/null/mdl.o -lm
dumpframe.o: In function `fitsError':
/.../dumpframe.c:2156: undefined reference to `ffrprt'
dumpframe.o: In function `dfFinishFrame':
/.../dumpframe.c:2175: undefined reference to `ffinit'
/.../dumpframe.c:2176: undefined reference to `ffcrim'
/.../dumpframe.c:2197: undefined reference to `ffppr'
/.../dumpframe.c:2198: undefined reference to `ffclos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'gasoline.dfTest' failed
make[1]: *** [gasoline.dfTest] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/grondjj/Code/gasoline'
Makefile:457: recipe for target 'null' failed
make: *** [null] Error 2
```

Here are the relevant lines from the Makefile for **make null**

```
 FITS_LIB = -L/usr/lib/ -lcfitsio

 BASE_LD_FLAGS = $(PNG_LIB) $(GSL_LIB) $(FITS_LIB)

 NULL_LD_FLAGS   = $(BASE_LD_FLAGS) 

 null:
      cd $(NULL_MDL); make "CC=$(CC)" "CFLAGS=$(NULL_CFLAGS)"
      make $(EXE) "CFLAGS=$(NULL_CFLAGS)" "LD_FLAGS=$(NULL_LD_FLAGS)"\
           "MDL=$(NULL_MDL)" "XOBJ=$(NULL_XOBJ)" "LIBMDL=$(NULL_LIBMDL)"
```

In **dumpframe.c** I include the **cfitsio** header **fitsio.h** along with the other inlcudes at the top of the file:

```
 #ifndef GSS_DUMPFRAME
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "fitsio.h"
```

The library was installed from source code. The source resides in **/usr/local/src/cfitsio/**, it was then installed via the following commands:

```
 $ ./configure --prefix=/usr
 $ make shared
 $ make install
 $ make clean
```

Which results in the libraries (**libcfitsio.a**, **libcfitsio.so**, **libcfitsio.so.5**, **libcfitsio.so.5.3.39**) being installed in **/usr/lib/** and the auxiliary files (**longnam.h**, **fitsio.h**, **fitsio2.h**, **drvrsmem.h**) being installed in **/usr/include/**.

I am not sure what causes this, as the compiler does not complain about missing libraries or a missing **fitsio.h** header file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the library after the object files, not before.

Wrong:

```
gcc -g -I../mdl/null -DCHABRIER -DCHANGESOFT -DDENSITYU -DDENSITYUNOTP \
    -DDIFFUSION -DDODVDS -DDTADJUST -DEPSACCH -DPARTICLESPLIT -DPROMOTE \
   -DGASOLINE -DJEANSSOFT -DNSMOOTHINNER -DRTFORCE -DSETTRAPFPE -DSTARFORM \
   -DTHERMALCOND -DTOPHATFEEDBACK -DTWOPHASE -DVSIGVISC -DWENDLAND -DRADIATION \
   -DRADIATIONLUM -DDDSIMPLE -DR2PPBMAX -DCOOLING_METAL \
   -L/usr/lib/ -lcfitsio  -I/usr/include/fitsio.h \
   -o gasoline.dfTest main.o master.o param.o outtype.o pkd.o pst.o grav.o ewald.o \
   walk.o eccanom.o hypanom.o fdl.o htable.o smooth.o smoothfcn.o collision.o \
   qqsmooth.o cooling_metal.o cosmo.o romberg.o starform.o feedback.o millerscalo.o \
   supernova.o supernovaia.o startime.o stiff.o runge.o dumpframe.o dffuncs.o \
   dumpvoxel.o rotbar.o special.o ssio.o treezip.o log.o radiation.o erf.o v_sqrt1.o \
   ../mdl/null/mdl.o -lm
```

Right:

```
gcc -g -I../mdl/null -DCHABRIER -DCHANGESOFT -DDENSITYU -DDENSITYUNOTP \
    -DDIFFUSION -DDODVDS -DDTADJUST -DEPSACCH -DPARTICLESPLIT -DPROMOTE \
   -DGASOLINE -DJEANSSOFT -DNSMOOTHINNER -DRTFORCE -DSETTRAPFPE -DSTARFORM \
   -DTHERMALCOND -DTOPHATFEEDBACK -DTWOPHASE -DVSIGVISC -DWENDLAND -DRADIATION \
   -DRADIATIONLUM -DDDSIMPLE -DR2PPBMAX -DCOOLING_METAL \
   -o gasoline.dfTest main.o master.o param.o outtype.o pkd.o pst.o grav.o ewald.o \
   walk.o eccanom.o hypanom.o fdl.o htable.o smooth.o smoothfcn.o collision.o \
   qqsmooth.o cooling_metal.o cosmo.o romberg.o starform.o feedback.o millerscalo.o \
   supernova.o supernovaia.o startime.o stiff.o runge.o dumpframe.o dffuncs.o \
   dumpvoxel.o rotbar.o special.o ssio.o treezip.o log.o radiation.o erf.o v_sqrt1.o \
   ../mdl/null/mdl.o -lcfitsio -lm
```

Note that the `-I/usr/include/cfitsio.h` option does no good, though it also does no harm given that the header is in `/usr/include`.  The `-I` option takes a directory name, not a file name.  Similarly, the `-L/usr/lib` option does no good, though it too does no harm either.  The `/usr/lib` library is searched automatically.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why the order needs to be changed. I am currently editing a Makefile given to me, and the order things get put in are "predefined", meaning the template wants to have -lcfitsio before the object files. I am aware that the library with the .a  extension might cause problems, as apposed to the .so extensions.

Comment: Given the makefile, the problem is probably that the `LD_FLAGS` macro contains library information but is listed before the object files in the linker command line.  If you're in charge of the `makefile`, one way around this is to use `LDFLAGS` to set library directories (`-L/opt/whatever/lib`) a separate `LDLIBS` or `LDLIBES` macro to specify the libraries (`-lwhatever`) which is then listed _after_ the object files in the linker command. This is mostly traditional.  Without knowing what is in the relevant bits of your makefile(s) — which you aren't in charge of — it's hard to help much more.

Comment: Some systems allow you to list libraries anywhere on the command line; it appears that the system this makefile originated on is one such system.  It also appears you're using a system that doesn't afford you the luxury of allowing libraries anywhere — welcome to the majority of the 'real world'.  See the duplicate Q&A for information about `--as-needed` and see whether that helps you. Yes, it's a nuisance. Well designed (or previously ported) packages compile correctly on both types of system, by listing libraries after objects. Apparently, this package hasn't encountered this problem before.